# Three.js postprocessing not working with effectcomposer

Tags: three.js

Outlines are not being created. I attempted a BloomFilter as well and it looks the same as if I didn't add any filters.

What could be the issue here?

```
// in global scope
const clock = new THREE.Clock();

// in initialization
this.composer = new EffectComposer(this.renderer);
this.composer.addPass(new RenderPass(this.scene, this.camera.camera_object));
this.composer.addPass(new EffectPass(this.camera.camera_object, new OutlineEffect(this.renderer, this.camera.camera_object, {
  defaultThickness: 0.01,
  defaultColor: [0, 0, 0],
  defaultAlpha: 0.8,
  defaultKeepAlive: true
})));

// in render loop

this.composer.render(clock.getDelta());
```

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to see the error without a full sample of the code. PostProcessing effects require the following:

- Load the postprocessing lib. In the example below I provided the full URL to for effects.
- Create the effect pass. A `new THREE.OutlinePass` or `new THREE.UnrealBloomPass` or similar.
- Add effect with `composer.addPass([your_pass])`.

Here is a minimal CodePen sample using both a `OutlinePass` and `UnrealBloomPass`:

https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/qBaLmZK?editors=1010

[image]

Note that `OutlinePass` requires `selectedObjects` to be an array with the objects that you want to affect.